# Find occurances of custom tag in HTML, perform function and replace tag with function output

Tags: php, regex, templates, content-management-system

This is probably a really easy question, so apologies for not being more challenging!

I am developing an in house CMS which uses a templating system.

To make this CMS as extendable as possible I want to use "modules". Hence in the template files I want to put custom HTML tags which represent modules.

This will look like:

`<p><Module name="newsTicker" property="value" anotherProperty="anotherValue" /></p>`

I get my template file by using:

```
ob_start();
include "templatefile.tpl";
$buffer= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Now I want to go through the contents of `$buffer` and for every occurance of `<Module name="moduleName" />` I want to `include "moduleName.class.php"`, create a new instance of that class, run the `getOutput()` function of that module and put the return value in where that `<Module />` tag used to be.

I have no idea how to go about that... :/ Any ideas?

If you don't understand think about a news ticker. I may write some code that looks through the news table in my database and makes a list of the 10 latest news stories, then it outputs it to a html `<ul>`. I want to abstract this so that it can be used on many pages. So in my template for the home page I might have the tag `<Module name="newsTicker" />`. Now when I visit the home page I need to look through the home page tpl file and I'll find where it says `<Module name="newsTicker" />`, I'll extract the `name` attribute and include a class based on that name (in this case it will be `newsTicker.class.php`). This will have a function called `getOutput()` so I will be able to something similar to: `$output = $current_module->getOutput();` and then I need to go back to my tpl file and change the original `<Module name="newsTicker" />` for the contents of `$output`.

Thanks for your help. :)

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use DOMDocument to find `Module` elements (I would use lowercase only personally).
- Store `name` attribute.
- `include_once` the class based on `name` attribute (skip if using autoloading).
- Use `$class = new $name`.
- Remove original `Module` DOM element and `appendChild` of `$class->getOutput()`.

Comment: that looks good, but will it work if these template files aren't full HTML files? For instance the files I will be working with may be just a block of content within a page, rather than a whole HTML document.

Comment: @Thomas Yes it should work, however you may need to extract just from the `body` element when you `$dom->saveHTML()`.